# How to conver the time type like '2006-11-06T09:49:43.000+08:00' to year-month-day hour: minutes: seconds

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.5

```
import time
temp_time ='2006-11-06T09:49:43.000+08:00'
time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",temp_time)
```

I get an error as follow:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-97b64e318f17> in <module>()
   1 import time
   2 temp_time ='2006-11-06T09:49:43.000+08:00'
----> 3 time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",temp_time)

TypeError: Tuple or struct_time argument required
```

\Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the string to a time object with [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) first.

```
>>> import time
>>> temp_time = '2006-11-06T09:49:43.000+08:00'
>>> s_time = time.strptime(temp_time, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000+08:00")
>>> time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", s_time)
'2006-11-06 09:49:43'
```

Comment: thanks ,good answer.
by the way, if the temp_time is a dataframe, like:
0    2006-11-06T09:49:43.000+08:00
1    2006-11-06T09:49:16.000+08:00
2    2006-11-06T09:49:45.000+08:00
3    2006-11-06T09:50:49.000+08:00
4    2006-11-06T09:50:22.000+08:00
Name: lending_time, dtype: object
what should i do!